# Simplicity of group of order $72$ follows to solvability?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we want to show that group of order $72$ is solvable. Why

**Definition:** The group $G$ is called solvable if there exists abelian normal tower, i.e. $$\{e\}=G_0\vartriangleleft G_1\vartriangleleft\dots \vartriangleleft G_n=G,$$ such that $G_{i+1}/G_{i}$ is abelian group.

I know the method of showing that any group of order $72$ is NOT simple.

In order to show that any group of order $72$ is solvable why it's enough to show that it NOT simple?

Would be very grateful for detailed explanation. In some sense I am not able to understand the relation between simplicity and solvability.

Comment: It's well-known that non-Abelian groups of order $<60$ are never simple.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, is there any alternative explanation?

Comment: Burnside p^aq^b?

Comment: As a problem, showing that a group of order 72 is soluble only makes sense if you have already proved that groups of smaller order--dividing 72 properly--are also soluble.

Comment: Consider Lord Shark's hint together with the useful fact that if $H\unlhd G$, then $G$ is solvable if and only if $H$ and $G/H$ are both solvable.